# postgreSQL and joining on alias

Tags: postgresql, join, left-join

I have a query that, in very simplified form, looks like this:

```
SELECT aa, bb, xx
FROM (VALUES ('a1', 'b1'), ('a2', 'b2')) as T1(aa, bb)
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT xx FROM (VALUES
    ('a1', 'y1'), ('x2', 'y2')) as T2(xx, yy)
) as T3 ON T1.aa = T3.xx ;
```

which executes to produce this:

```
 aa | bb |   xx   
----+----+--------
 a1 | b1 | a1
 a2 | b2 | (NULL)
(2 rows)
```

In real life the column `xx` is defined using a case statement and alias:

```
SELECT
    ...,
    (CASE WHEN rgr.age_years < 18 THEN '< 18'
          WHEN rgr.age_years < 36 THEN '26-35'
          WHEN rgr.age_years < 46 THEN '36-45'
          WHEN rgr.age_years < 56 THEN '46-55'
          WHEN rgr.age_years < 130 THEN '> 55' END)
        as row_name,
    ...
FROM
    (VALUES ('< 18'), ('26-35'), ('36-45'),
            ('46-55'), ('> 55'))
    as prn(possible_row_name)
LEFT JOIN other_table rgr 
  ON prn.possible_row_name = ??row_name??
```

Obviously `??row_name??` is an alias and so is not available at the time I specify the join.  But I've not found the right formulation.

The point is simply that I'm doing a select on table `rgr` and I want all the age tranches present, even if no entity satisfies that number.

Comment: You can't reference a column alias on the same level where you defined it. You will need to move the SELECT with the CASE expression into a derived table (aka sub-query)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create the column on the fly inside the table expression `rgr`, as in:

```
SELECT
    ...,
    rgr.row_name,
    ...
FROM
    (VALUES ('< 18'), ('26-35'), ('36-45'),
            ('46-55'), ('> 55'))
    as prn(possible_row_name)
LEFT JOIN ( -- table expression rgr defined here
  select t.*,
     CASE WHEN rgr.age_years < 18 THEN '< 18'
          WHEN rgr.age_years < 36 THEN '26-35'
          WHEN rgr.age_years < 46 THEN '36-45'
          WHEN rgr.age_years < 56 THEN '46-55'
          WHEN rgr.age_years < 130 THEN '> 55' END
        as row_name
  from other_table t
) rgr ON prn.possible_row_name = rgr.row_name
```

Comment: Is there no efficiency concern from the `t.*` rather than specifying the needed columns?

Comment: Efficiency is a concern that is not included in the question. Anyway, the answer is no. In good (or at least decent) engines the columns are not materialized unless they are used in the external queries.

Comment: I agree the question wasn't about efficiency, but one becomes more efficient by asking the question. ;-)  In the event, for simple tables, it's actually faster to use *, but I didn't check for tables with a very large number of columns.